# Fieldname truncated

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, firebird, firebird2.1

I'm trying to migrate from Delphi 7 to Delphi 2010.

My first difficulty is a FIELDNAME truncation.

I'm using a table with a column where the name exceeds the size of 30 characters (31 chars exactly).

When the query opens, an exception occours:

```
Field 'NUM_DIAS_ATRASO_BLOQ_FAT_PESSOA' not found
```

After I changed the field name (with an alias like `"NUM_DIAS_ATRASO_BLOQ_FAT_PESSO"`), everything comes fine....

At Delphi7 this problem doesn't occours!

How can I solve this???

Comment: Now using dbx and was using something else back then? You're hitting a limitation imposed by 'MIDASNAME' in 'dsintf.pas'. Of course this is a far fetched guess since you've decided to provide no information at all..

Comment: Problem solved... I installed updates 4 and 5!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved!

Installed updates 4 and 5.